# httpRequest does not load image parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

This is my original cloud code function to resize the photo, it is working fine with small size of photo like if photo size is less than 1 MB.This function return error that success/error was not called.Than i spend my more time to investigate this function and made this function more simpler, see my next comments for simpler function...

```
Parse.Cloud.define("mediaPhotoResize", function(request, response) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
    var parseMediaId = request.params.objectId;
    var Image = require("parse-image");
    var photoUrl = request.params.photoUrl;
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            url: photoUrl

        }).then(function(responseHTTP) {
            var image = new Image();
            return image.setData(responseHTTP.buffer);

        }).then(function(image) {
            return image.scale({
                ratio: 0.05
            });

        }).then(function(image) {
            return image.setFormat("JPEG");

        }).then(function(image) {
            return image.data();

        }).then(function(buffer) {
            var base64 = buffer.toString("base64");
            var cropped = new Parse.File('thumbnail_photo.jpg', {base64: base64});
            return cropped.save();

        }).then(function(cropped) {
            var ParseMedia = Parse.Object.extend("ParseMedia");
            var mediaQuery = new Parse.Query(ParseMedia);
            mediaQuery.get(parseMediaId, {
                success: function(mediaObj) {
                    var fileObj = {};
                    fileObj["name"] = cropped.name();
                    fileObj["url"] = cropped.url();
                    fileObj["__type"] = "File";
                    mediaObj.set("mediaThumbnail", fileObj);
                    mediaObj.save(null, {
                        success: function(mediaObj) {
                            response.success(mediaObj);
                        }, error: function(error) {
                            response.error(error);
                        }
                    });
                }, error: function(error) {
                    response.error(error);
                }
            });
        });
});
```

Than i made my function more simpler to check the Cloud.Code.httpRequest request, is this respond me on time or not And i found that this response me an error "Execution Time out" only with large image.Please check my modified cloud code function

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("parseImageTest", function(request, response) {
var Image = require("parse-image"); 
Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({ 
  url: "http://files.parsetfss.com/a7b7ddfe-bcd9-4046-be12-5b155005b5e3/tfss-027f8804-9e51-4f80-ba3d-dbb3948bb80c-parse-media-photo.jpg", 
  success: function(responsehttp) { 
    // The file contents are in response.buffer. 
    var image = new Image(); 
    return image.setData(responsehttp.buffer, { 
      success: function() { 
        response.success("Image is " + image.width() + "x" + image.height() + "."); 
    }, 
    error: function(error) { 
      response.error(error);
    } 
   })}, 
   error: function(error) { response.error(error); } 
});
});
```

Comment: what errors are output? log everything.

Comment: Above code is a little portion of my code, i want scaling thumbnail of actual image, Getting error "success/error was not called" in cloud code function, according to my more R&D i noticed that with large size image of dimension like 3264x2448 the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest does not load the image for further processing.

Comment: Ah.. yes I do think there is a resolution limit.. will try to get confirmation.

Comment: i have updated question with my code, please review my code

Comment: Looks like the limits are as follows:  Image buffer cannot be greater than 10MB.. target resizes cannot be larger than 2000 in either dimension.